# php imagick annotation antialiasing

Tags: php, imagick, antialiasing

I have a webcam and want to add some annotations to image, but antialiasing works strange. I'll try to explain:

I have an image like this: [image: Source image]

Then I add semi-transparent rectangle and put text over it:

```
        //  add background black rectangle
        $draw->setFillColor('black'); 
        $draw->setFillOpacity(0.5);
        $draw->rectangle( 0, 10, $cam['width'], 70 );    // Draw the rectangle 
        //  add lead text
        $draw->setFont('ARIALBD.TTF');
        $draw->setFontSize(14);
        $draw->setFillColor('white');
        $draw->annotation(20, 35, $cam['text']);
        //  add timestamp
        $draw->setFont('ARIAL.TTF');
        $draw->setFontSize(12);
        $draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#f3ac01'));
        $draw->annotation(20, 50, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $img->drawImage($draw);
```

And get something like this:

[image: Adding text]

Huh, but timestamp looks ulgy(look at minutes/seconds). Trying to disable antialiasing:

```
$draw->setTextAntialias(false);
```

and now it looks still ugly(look at hours), but now it has sharp edges:

[image: antialiasing turned off]

How can I get result with smart antialiasing, like this(I know PS uses own antialiasing, but IMagickDraw deal real bad result):

[image: Want this]

Comment: Arial isn't "good font"? Don't think so

Comment: Some fonts work better. Some fonts and systems support sub-pixel rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks more like the compression level of the whole image when saved than the antialiasing, have a look at [setCompressionQuality](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php), and tweak the compression quality until you avoid the "blurriness" you have in the picture.

Comment: Wasn't the compression then? I will remember the setTextAntialias then just in case I need to use it in the nearby future. Thanks for the accept anyway then

Comment: Result: http://ctepeo.by/share/2012-11-20_15-47-20.png 
Looks charming! Code I've used:

$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$img->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$img->setCompressionQuality(100);
and now everything is ok! There's no default value in manual php.net, so I thought it was 100.

Comment: ah then it was the compression xD, anyway I would suggest not using 100, if you cut it down to 90 or 85 you will get almost the same quality, but with the file size much smaller. Try different values until you find a good one that is balanced between size and quality. Normally 85 is pretty safe. If you are interested in the image compression there is a great library out there jpegfit that allows you to set the compression to X while fitting the file size withing Y, i recommend it.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3810-PHP-Optimize-images-to-fit-in-a-given-file-size-limit.html

Comment: It should do but I'm not completely sure, png's have compression level normally so give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Try the different font first. Here is example of [open sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sans) ([another link](http://viziblr.com/news/2012/1/14/the-open-sans-typeface-ndash-cool-sublime-and-free.html)) font.
[image]

Comment: Using custom fonts in ImageMagick on PHP can be quite a headache I imagine, since you must install those fonts on the server.